# Confusion about \@afterheading, \@afterindentfalse and paragraphs inside other environments

Tags: sectioning, environments, indentation, theorems

I am a package author writing a package for my company. I am trying to provide theorem-like environments using `amsthm` for easy use.

I need to find a way to realize the following behaviour:

- If content starts right after `\begin{environment}` or immediately on the next line, then it should be placed immediately after the environment label, except if it is spanning the entire linewidth, e.g. `enumerate` or `align`.
- If one or more empty lines are left at the start of the environment, the content needs to start below the environment label, and the first line of content must not be indented (like after a heading).
- Indenting inside the environment for new paragraphs must still be possible.

I have investigated the following ideas pointed out in the MWE, but none achieves the desired results.

```latex
    \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}


    \makeatletter
    \declaretheorem[
        postheadhook={
            },
    ]{theoremA}

    \declaretheorem[
        postheadhook={
            \mbox{}
            },
    ]{theoremB}

    \declaretheorem[
        postheadhook={
            \mbox{}
            \@afterindentfalse
            \@afterheading
            },
    ]{theoremC}

    \declaretheorem[%
        postheadhook = {%
        \leavevmode
        \everypar{\setbox\z@\lastbox\everypar{}}
        },
    ]{theoremD}

    \declaretheorem[%
        postheadhook = {%
        \setbox\z@\lastbox
        },
    ]{theoremE}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Type A}
        \begin{theoremA}
            This line is exactly where it ought to be.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem. This is fine.
        \end{theoremA}

        \begin{theoremA}

            This line is starting right after the label, which it should \textbf{not} do.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremA}

        \begin{theoremA}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration should start on its own line, and \textbf{not} after the label.
        \end{theoremA}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Type B}

        \begin{theoremB}
            This line is correctly broken to a new line and staring right after the theorem label as intended.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem. This is as intended.
        \end{theoremB}

        \begin{theoremB}

            This line is correctly starting on a new line, however, I do \textbf{not} want it to be indented (just for the first line).

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremB}

        \begin{theoremB}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration now starts on its own line as intended. Notice the topsep is being kept as intended.
        \end{theoremB}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        % \everypar{ASDF}
        \section{Type C}

        \begin{theoremC}
            This line is starting right after the label as intended.

            This other line is \textbf{not} indented, and this is \textbf{not} the behaviour I expect.

            However, if I add another line, this one gets indented as expected.
        \end{theoremC}
        %
        \begin{theoremC}

            This line is correctly moved to a new line.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremC}
        %
        \begin{theoremC}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration now starts on its own line. Good. However, the topsep is ignored, which is \textbf{not} what I want.
        \end{theoremC}
    \end{minipage}

    \pagebreak

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Type D}

        \begin{theoremD}
            This line is starting right after the label as intended.

            This other line is \textbf{not} indented, and this is \textbf{not} the behaviour I expect.

            However, if I add another line, this one gets indented as expected.
        \end{theoremD}
        %
        \begin{theoremD}

            This line is correctly moved to a new line and correctly indented.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremD}
        %
        \begin{theoremD}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration now starts on its own line. Good. However, the topsep is ignored, which is \textbf{not} what I want.
        \end{theoremD}

        \textbf{In short, this behaves exactly like Type~C.}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Type E}

        \begin{theoremE}
            This line is exactly where it ought to be.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem. This is fine.
        \end{theoremE}

        \begin{theoremE}

            This line is starting right after the label, which it should \textbf{not} do.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremE}

        \begin{theoremE}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration should start on its own line, and \textbf{not} after the label.
        \end{theoremE}

        \textbf{In short, this behaves exactly like Type~A.}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Future tests}
    \end{minipage}


    \end{document}
```

*please forgive the long MWE, but I assure you it is the minimal amount of structure to display the comparison.*

My example compiles to this:

[image]

See the comments inline for exactly how the MWE deviates from the desired/expected behaviour.

I'm happy to be pointed in another direction, just remember that I can not just use `\noindent` for the document authors, or require them to put empty `\mbox{}` inside their document.

### Addition 1:

I have tested two new cases following the suggestions in the given answer and comment (Type D and Type E). However, they don't provide a satisfying answer. See attached screenshot:

[image]

The additional code has been added directly to the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

From the ltpara.dtx chapter of source2e.pdf:

Thus out of the box, TEX offers the possibility to put some special code into
`\everypar` to gain control at (more or less) the start of the paragraph. For example, in LaTeX and a number of packages, special code like the following is sometimes used:

```
\everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{} ...}
```

This removes the paragraph indentation box again (that was already placed by TEX), then resets `\everypar` so that it doesn’t do anything on the next paragraph start and then does whatever it wants to do, e.g., in an `\item` of a list it will typeset the label in front of the paragraph text. However, there is only one such `\everypar` token register and if different packages and/or the kernel all attempt to add their own code here, coordination is very difficult if not impossible.

`\@afterheading` contains this code, although it first checks `\if@afterindent`.  But all you really need is the `\everypar` bit.  The big question is whether Theorem is already using `\everypar`.

---

Theorem appears to test for a label and absorb any `\par`s.  `\null` isn't enough to satisfy the test, but `\strut` is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{thmtools}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}


    \declaretheorem{theoremA}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
        \section{Type A}
        \begin{theoremA}
            This line is exactly where it ought to be.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem. This is fine.
        \end{theoremA}

        \begin{theoremA}\strut\newline
            This line is no longer starting right after the label, as desired.

            This other line is indented, as it constitutes a new paragraph inside the theorem.
        \end{theoremA}

        \begin{theoremA}\strut%\vspace{\dimexpr \itemsep-\baselineskip}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item line A
                \item line B
            \end{enumerate}
            The enumeration should start on its own line, and \textbf{not} after the label.
        \end{theoremA}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I tried various combinations with ``\everypar`` in the meantime. For TheoremC2, I can use ``\everypar`` easily to refer to the first paragraph and change it accordingly. However, for TheoremC1 the first paragraph (according to ``\everypar``) is the line "This other line is not ...", as somehow the first sentence of TheoremC1 is typeset before calling ``\everypar``. Do you have a suggestion how to adress this?

Comment: Try `postheadhook={{\setbox\z@\lastbox}}`.  This assumes that postheadhook is implmented by \everypar in the first paragraph, and probably ends with an automatic `\everypar{}`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately, it does not work. Perhaps your assumption is wrong, but I am not capable of understanding, how ``amsthm`` and ``thmtools`` implement the labeling for theorems. From what I can tell, the relevant definitions arre carried out in ``thmtools.sty`` in line 49 by loading ``thm-patch.sty`` and in my case ``thm-amsthm.sty``, however, I can not figure out where the actual theorems are typeset and where the postheadhook gets inserted.
I added your suggestions as examples to the MWE with the corresponding output.

Comment: As it turns out, you really don't need `\everypar` or `postheadhook`.

Comment: You are right about ``\strut``, but that puts all the work on the document authors, in the same fashion as using ``\mbox{}`` or ``\noindent``, which I explicitely excluded as a solution. When I put the ``\strut`` macro into ``postheadhook``, it behaves the same as ``\leavevmode``, i.e. it removes indenting from the second paragraph of the first example.

Comment: Theorem starts with `\item` and behaves like any trivlist.  It ignores spaces and \par normally, just as `\newline` will igve a warning (There is no line here to end).  I was able to create an environment where the first line had to be passed as an optonal argument, but that also requires user involvement.